# why doesnt div display at proper coordinates?

Tags: jquery, image, iterator, coordinates, erb

So I've created an erb block that iterates through the coordinates for each image, and then displays div.tagged for each image at the given coordinates. In this particular case the block iterates through 2 images, div.tagged shows up once per image however div.tagged's position is the same for each image. Anyone have any ideas as to why? Here is the [HTML is generated](https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6050853)

**erb block**

```
<div class="container">
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
        <span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"> </span>
        <div class="image_panel"><br>
            <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
        <div class='planetmap'></div>
    </div>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span.i_connection").each(function() {
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    $(".tagged_box").css("display","block");
    $(".tagged").css("border","5px solid red");

        $('.planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+pos_height+'px;left:'+xpos+'px;top:'+ypos+'px;" ><div class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
            pos_height+'px;" ></div>')
});   //END OF SPAN.CONNECTION ITERATION
}); //END OF JQUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a few problems.

1) you aren't using the CSS position: absolute within your 'tagged' class.
2) you are declaring multiple .planetmap's (one per loop) and appending the content each time.

If it's intentional that you want many .planetmaps, restrict your jQuery to operate on the local copy only using something like $(this).next('.image_panel).find('.planetmap')

Here is a JS Fiddle of the CSS position addition : http://jsfiddle.net/ksf3A/ Your left / rights are off & it's showing multiple images as per your HTML.

Maybe you want:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image_panel"><br>
         <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
        <div class='planetmap'></div>
    </div>

<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
        <span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"> </span>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
</div>
```

instead? I'm assuming of course this is multiple connections on one device, not multiple devices with multiple connections (in which you need a secondary outer loop of devices)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It actually is for multiple devices with multiple connections. I thought I would need multiple .planetmaps because this is how the .tagged div is appended, but it would seem that doing so is causing the second to display incorrectly, huh?

Comment: in that case, you need to create a loop of devices, and then loop through the multiple devices. E.g. 

foreach device
   << device image & html>>
   foreach device_connection
       << connection tag for JS >>

Also, why are you using JS to formulate the html - you could write it straight out.

Comment: The erb block loops through the device images and displays them dynamically based on the user's selection. Would I have to loop through them in my JS as well?